# What does “exec some_cmd &” mean in bash

Tags: bash

I found a use of `exec some_cmd &` in [this script](https://gist.github.com/camshaft/f0359b6aaaade2a11d73):

```
...
exec elixir \
  -pa _build/prod/consolidated \
  --no-halt \
  --erl "+A$THREAD_COUNT" \
  --erl "+K true" \
  --erl "-smp auto" \
  --erl "+scl false" \
  --erl "+spp true" \
  --erl "+swt low" \
  --erl "+sbwt long" \
  --sname $NODE \
  --cookie $COOKIE \
  -S mix run \
    --no-compile \
$@ \
&
...
```

`exec some_cmd` replaces the shell with `some_cmd`. `some_cmd &` spawns `some_cmd` as a child process in background.
So what happens when combining them?

I gave it a try with bash 3.2 and the result shows that it looks like it spawns a background process:

```
# script
echo "Shell PID: $$"
exec sh -c 'echo "Child PID: $$"' &
BG_PID=$!
echo "Background process PID: $BG_PID"

# output
Shell PID: 8852
Background process PID: 8853
Child PID: 8853
```

Though I'm not sure whether it is exactly the same as `some_cmd &`.

Comment: [This](http://wiki.tcl.tk/4304) looks related but doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @Steven thanks but that's about _Tcl_'s `exec` command, not Bash's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `exec` command has no effect in this case. Normally, `exec` would prevent bash from forking before calling `execve`, but in this case bash forks anyway because you said `&`.

So `exec some_cmd &` is the same as `some_cmd &`.

You might use `exec` with `&` anyway if you need to use one of the `exec` flags. Type `help exec` to see what flags `exec` supports.